# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated crashes in ios 6.0 ipad simulator

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to dismiss modal view controllers:

```
- (IBAction)done {
#ifdef __IPHONE_5_0
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])
        [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    else
#endif
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If I runt he simulator using iOS 4.3 iPad, it uses `self.parentViewController` and works fine. However, when I runt he simulator using iOS 6.0 iPad the simulator crashes right after the view is dismissed using `self.presentingViewController`.

I do not have an actual iPad to test on... any ideas?

EDIT:

below is the code that creates the modal view controller.

```
NSArray* errors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Errors" ofType:@"plist"]];

UIViewController* vc;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    DocumentsViewController_iPad* docsVC = [[DocumentsViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentsViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
    docsVC.documents = errors;
    docsVC.errors = YES;
    docsVC.navTitle = @"Troubleshooting";
    vc = docsVC;
} else {
    DocumentsViewController* docsVC = [[DocumentsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    docsVC.documents = errors;
    docsVC.errors = YES;
    docsVC.navTitle = @"Troubleshooting";
    vc = docsVC;
}

vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Yes, you should use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` as @rdelmar said
- You should call it on presentingViewController, not parent
- You can skip going to the presenting controller and dismiss `self`, it will forward this message to the presenting controller if needed.

Answer (score 1):

dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: is depreciated, use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead.

Comment: Deprecated, but not gone. Using it shouldn't cause a crash, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just changed to dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: and it is still crashing.

Comment: @Mausimo, Have you added an exception breakpoint to see if it will pinpoint the line the error is occurring on? I suspect your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I have, the break point does not fire. I am going to try to get a device tomorrow for testing.

Comment: I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. objc_msgSend Please see my edit. I added the code that is creating the modalViewController.